# How to define schema for custom type in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, case-class

The following example code tries to put some case objects into a dataframe. The code includes the definition of a case object hierarchy and a case class using this trait:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

sealed trait Some
case object AType extends Some
case object BType extends Some

case class Data( name : String, t: Some)

object Example {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName( "Example" )
      .setMaster( "local[*]")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val df = sc.parallelize( Seq( Data( "a", AType), Data( "b", BType) ), 4).toDF()
    df.show()
  }
}
```

When executing the code, I unfortunately encounter the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Some is not supported
```

### Questions

- Is there a possibility to add or define a schema for certain types (here type `Some`)?
- Does another approach exist to represent this kind of enumerations?

  - I tried to use `Enumeration` directly, but also without success. (see below)

Code for `Enumeration`:

```
object Some extends Enumeration {
  type Some = Value
  val AType, BType = Value
}
```

Thanks in advance. I hope, that the best approach is not to use strings instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Spark 2.0.0+**:

`UserDefinedType` has been made private in Spark 2.0.0 and as for now it has no `Dataset` friendly replacement.

See: [SPARK-14155 (Hide UserDefinedType in Spark 2.0)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14155)

Most of the time statically typed `Dataset` can serve as replacement 
There is a pending Jira [SPARK-7768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7768) to make UDT API public again with target version 2.4.

See also [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/1560062)

**Spark < 2.0.0**

> Is there a possibility to add or define a schema for certain types (here type Some)?

I guess the answer depends on how badly you need this. It looks like it is possible to create an `UserDefinedType` but it requires access to `DeveloperApi` and is not exactly straightforward or well documented.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[SomeUDT])
sealed trait Some
case object AType extends Some
case object BType extends Some

class SomeUDT extends UserDefinedType[Some] {
  override def sqlType: DataType = IntegerType

  override def serialize(obj: Any) = {
    obj match {
      case AType => 0
      case BType => 1
    }
  }

  override def deserialize(datum: Any): Some = {
    datum match {
      case 0 => AType
      case 1 => BType
    }
  }

  override def userClass: Class[Some] = classOf[Some]
}
```

You should probably override `hashCode` and `equals` as well.

Its PySpark counterpart can look like this:

```py
from enum import Enum, unique
from pyspark.sql.types import UserDefinedType, IntegerType

class SomeUDT(UserDefinedType):
    @classmethod
    def sqlType(self):
        return IntegerType()

    @classmethod
    def module(cls):
        return cls.__module__

    @classmethod 
    def scalaUDT(cls): # Required in Spark < 1.5
        return 'net.zero323.enum.SomeUDT'

    def serialize(self, obj):
        return obj.value

    def deserialize(self, datum):
        return {x.value: x for x in Some}[datum]

@unique
class Some(Enum):
    __UDT__ = SomeUDT()
    AType = 0
    BType = 1
```

In Spark < 1.5 Python UDT requires a paired Scala UDT, but it look like it is no longer the case in 1.5.

For a simple UDT like you can use simple types (for example `IntegerType` instead of whole `Struct`).

Comment: Thanks @zero323! Are you involved in the UDT 2.4 effort at all? I made a bunch of posts in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7768 trying to figure these things out.