# Spark: Populating Cassandra UDTValue as a DataFrame column

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I am trying to create a Cassandra UDT from some columns from my data frame. I want to add this UDT column to the data frame and save this to the Cassandra table.
My code looks like:

```
val asUDT = udf((keys: Seq[String], values: Seq[String]) =>
   UDTValue.fromMap(keys.zip(values).filter {
      case (k, null) => false
      case _ => true
    }.toMap))

val keys = array(mapKeys.map(lit): _*)
val values = array(mapValues.map(col): _*)
return df.withColumn("targetColumn", (asUDT(keys, values))
```

However, I am receiving the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type AnyRef is not supported.

Please let me know how I can save a UDT value as a column in my data frame.
Any pointers on how I can get this to work will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: To be able to insert custom class into `DataFrame` you need proper annotation on the class and Spark UDT which describes how to serialize and deserialize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define schema for custom type in Spark SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440461/how-to-define-schema-for-custom-type-in-spark-sql)

Comment: I saw that one but that needs me to define structure for the dataframe upfront, doesnt it? I was hoping I could just create a custom column and add it to the dataframe.

Comment: No, you can return custom type from udf.

Comment: Oh alright.. Would you be able to explain how I can do that. I am not quite familiar with this yet..

Comment: Truth be told I have no idea what is `UDTValue` and how it is represented :) Could you provide some details? What kind of data do you keep there?

Comment: Spark Cassandra connector exposes UDTValue to de/serialize the data. I have different types of UDTs, the simplest one looks like this:   `case class metric(value: Float, ccy: String, bill_no: String)`

Comment: IMHO if you have something that can be easily represented as a case class with supported fields it is better to use it directly as StructType. There is no value in UDT and every operation you'll try to perform on that will require quite a lot of wrangling not to mention will be more expensive than using native types.

Comment: Ok.. but how do I do it. :(

Comment: Oh, case classes, including nested are supported out of the box. Try `case class Record(id: Long, metric: metric); sc.parallelize(Seq(Record(1L, metric(1.0f, "foo", "bar")))).toDF` :)