# Scala Spark Dataframe new column from object column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that contains a Polyline column (from Magellan).
I want to extract some fields of this column to new columns.
Here is an example of what I want to do :

```
spark.read
      .format("magellan")
      .load(My_Path)
      .withColumn("xcoordinates",$"polyline"("xcoordinates")) // Do not work
      .drop("polyline")
```

But then I get the error :

```
Can't extract value from polyline#1190: need struct type but got polyline;
```

Here is a sample of data :

DF : (id, polyline, otherColumns)

```
ID1, {"xcoordinates":[55.37,55.376],"indices":[0],"empty":false,"ycoordinates":[25.23,25.232],"boundingBox":{"xmin":55.376,"ymin":25.23,"xmax":55.376,"ymax":25.234},"valid":true,"type":3}, ...
ID2, {"xcoordinates":[55.37,55.376],"indices":[0],"empty":false,"ycoordinates":[25.23,25.232],"boundingBox":{"xmin":55.376,"ymin":25.23,"xmax":55.376,"ymax":25.234},"valid":true,"type":3}, ...
ID3, {"xcoordinates":[55.37,55.376],"indices":[0],"empty":false,"ycoordinates":[25.23,25.232],"boundingBox":{"xmin":55.376,"ymin":25.23,"xmax":55.376,"ymax":25.234},"valid":true,"type":3}, ...
```

And an example of expected output :

DF2 : (id, xcoordinates, otherColumns)

```
ID1, [55.37,55.376], ...
ID2, [55.37,55.376], ...
ID3, [55.37,55.376], ...
```

EDIT : 
I finally managed to do what I wanted :

```
import magellan.PolyLine

val xcoordinates = (data: PolyLine) => data.xcoordinates
val getXcoordinatesUDF = udf(xcoordinates)

 spark.read
          .format("magellan")
          .load(My_Path)
          .withColumn("xcoordinates",getXcoordinatesUDF($"polyline"))
          .drop("polyline")
```

Comment: [SparkSQL referencing attributes of UDT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33747851/9613318)

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks