# Dot product between two Vector columns of a DataFrame in Spark without UDF

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Let's consider a Spark DataFrame with 2 columns, each of them being of Vector type.
Is there a way that doesn't involve UDFs to compute the dot product between them?

I am using Spark 2.4 (on DataBricks, in case there is a solution involving their higher-order functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any reasonable* way of doing such thing as Vectors are not native types. Instead they implement `UserDefinedTypes` [and as such can be processed only indirectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747851/sparksql-referencing-attributes-of-udt/33757380).

If data is narrow you might consider converting to matching strongly typed `Dataset`, but it is unlikely to bring any serious improvement (if not decrease performance).

---

* One could derive highly indirect solution, fore example by:

- Adding unique ID
- Dumping vector to JSON.
- Reading JSON by reserializing to internal `StructType` representation.
- Exploding vector with `pos_explode` (`DenseVector`) or zipping indices and value (`SparseVector`)
- Self joining by unique and index.
- Aggregate.

Any such thing would be expensive and completely impractical.