# Column having list datatype : Spark HiveContext

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following code does aggregation and create a column with list datatype:

```
groupBy(
            "column_name_1"
        ).agg(
            expr("collect_list(column_name_2) "
                 "AS column_name_3")
        )
```

So it seems it is possible to have 'list' as column datatype in a dataframe.

I was wondering if I can write a udf that returns custom datatype, for example a python dict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define schema for custom type in Spark SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440461/how-to-define-schema-for-custom-type-in-spark-sql)

Answer (score 0):

The list is a representation of spark's Array datatype. You can try using the Map datatype (pyspark.sql.types.MapType).
an example of something which creates it is: pyspark.sql.functions.create_map which creates a map from several columns
That said if you want to create a custom aggregation function to do anything not already available in pyspark.sql.functions you will need to use scala.