# Spark SQL UDF with complex input parameter

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use UDF with input type Array of struct.
I have the following structure of data this is only relevant part of a bigger structure

```
|--investments: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |-- funding_round: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- company: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |    |-- permalink: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- funded_day: long (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- funded_month: long (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- funded_year: long (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- raised_amount: long (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- raised_currency_code: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- round_code: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- source_description: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |    |-- source_url: string (nullable = true)
```

I declared case classes:

```scala
case class Company(name: String, permalink: String)
case class FundingRound(company: Company, funded_day: Long, funded_month: Long, funded_year: Long, raised_amount: Long, raised_currency_code: String, round_code: String, source_description: String, source_url: String)
case class Investments(funding_round: FundingRound)
```

UDF declaration:

```scala
sqlContext.udf.register("total_funding", (investments:Seq[Investments])  => {
     val totals = investments.map(r => r.funding_round.raised_amount)
     totals.sum
})
```

When I'm executing the following transformation the result is as expected

```scala
scala> sqlContext.sql("""select total_funding(investments) from companies""")
res11: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: bigint]
```

But when an action executed like collect I have an error:

```
Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to $line33.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Investments
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error you see should be pretty much self-explanatory. There is a strict mapping between Catalyst / SQL types and Scala types which can be found in [the relevant section](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) of [the Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html).

In particular `struct` types are converted to `o.a.s.sql.Row` (in your particular case data will be exposed as `Seq[Row]`).

There are different methods which can be used to expose data as specific types:

- [Defining UDT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32440461/1560062) (user defined type) which [has been removed in 2.0.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14155) and has no replacement [for now](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7768).
- Converting `DataFrame` to `Dataset[T]` where `T` is a desired local type.

with only the former approach could be applicable in this particular scenario.

If you want to access `investments.funding_round.raised_amount` using UDF you'll need something like this:

```scala
val getRaisedAmount = udf((investments: Seq[Row]) => scala.util.Try(
  investments.map(_.getAs[Row]("funding_round").getAs[Long]("raised_amount"))
).toOption)
```

but simple `select` should be much safer and cleaner:

```scala
df.select($"investments.funding_round.raised_amount")
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple library which derives the necessary encoders for complex Product types based on the input type parameters.

https://github.com/lesbroot/typedudf

```scala
import typedudf.TypedUdf
import typedudf.ParamEncoder._

case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)
val fooUdf = TypedUdf((foo: Foo) => foo.x + foo.y.length)
df.withColumn("sum", fooUdf($"foo"))
```