# PySpark to Scala: UDF with StructType, GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some code written with PySpark, and I'm busy converting it to Scala. It's been going well, except now I'm struggling with user defined functions in Scala.

#### python

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()

a = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (10,)]).toDF(["index"]).withColumn("a1", F.lit(1)).withColumn("a2", F.lit(2)).withColumn("a3", F.lit(3))

a = a.select("index", F.struct(*('a' + str(c) for c in range(1, 4))).alias('a'))

a.show()

def a_to_b(a):
    # 1. check if a technical cure exists
    b = {}
    for i in range(1, 4):
        b.update({'b' + str(i): a[i - 1] ** 2})
    return b

a_to_b_udf = F.udf(lambda x: a_to_b(x), StructType(list(StructField("b" + str(x), IntegerType()) for x in range(1, 4))))

b = a.select("index", "a", a_to_b_udf(a.a).alias("b"))

b.show()
```

This yields:

```
+-----+-------+
|index|      a|
+-----+-------+
|    1|[1,2,3]|
|    2|[1,2,3]|
|    3|[1,2,3]|
|    4|[1,2,3]|
|    5|[1,2,3]|
|    6|[1,2,3]|
|    7|[1,2,3]|
|    8|[1,2,3]|
|    9|[1,2,3]|
|   10|[1,2,3]|
+-----+-------+
```

and

```
+-----+-------+-------+
|index|      a|      b|
+-----+-------+-------+
|    1|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|    2|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|    3|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|    4|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|    5|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|    6|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|    7|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|    8|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|    9|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
|   10|[1,2,3]|[1,4,9]|
+-----+-------+-------+
```

#### Scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// can ignore if running on spark-shell
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

var a = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10).toDF("index").withColumn("a1", lit(1)).withColumn("a2", lit(2)).withColumn("a3", lit(3))

// convert a{x} to struct column
a = a.select($"index", struct((1 to 3).map {x => col("a" + x)}.toList:_*).alias("a"))

a.show()

// this is where I am struggling, I have tried supplying a schema, but still get errors
val f = udf((a: Column) => {
  Seq(Math.pow(a(0).asInstanceOf[Double], 2), Math.pow(a(1).asInstanceOf[Double], 2), Math.pow(a(2).asInstanceOf[Double], 2))
})

val b = a.select($"index", $"a", f($"a").alias("b"))

// throws the below error
b.show()
```

I can show() the first DataFrame, but I get a casting error when trying to show `b`.

The error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Column
  at $line23.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:31)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried setting a schema for my UDF as I've done in Python, but I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how I can get around this issue? My example is simple, but what I need to do on the UDF is quite a lot of transformations before returning the struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel very silly, because I've been struggling since Friday afternoon.

From [Spark Sql UDF with complex input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413040/spark-sql-udf-with-complex-input-parameter),

> struct types are converted to `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

My problem was with the `Column` type that I was supplying to my function.

```
val f = udf((a: Column) => {
  Seq(Math.pow(a(0).asInstanceOf[Double], 2), Math.pow(a(1).asInstanceOf[Double], 2), Math.pow(a(2).asInstanceOf[Double], 2))
})
```

I was supposed to use `Row` instead.

```
val f = udf((a: Row) => {
  println("testing")
  Seq(Math.pow(a(0).asInstanceOf[Int], 2).asInstanceOf[Int],
    Math.pow(a(1).asInstanceOf[Int], 2).asInstanceOf[Int],
    Math.pow(a(2).asInstanceOf[Int], 2).asInstanceOf[Int])
})
```