# Spark array struct and UDFs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, user-defined-functions

I have the following schema and I want to add a new column called distance. This colum compute the distance between the tow time series of each row: time_series1 and time_series2

```
|-- websites: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
|    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
|-- countryId1: integer (nullable = false)
|-- countryId2: integer (nullable = false)
|-- time_series1: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- _1: float (nullable = false)
|    |    |-- _2: date (nullable = true)
|-- time_series2: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- _1: float (nullable = false)
|    |    |-- _2: date (nullable = true)
```

So I use the udf function to define this new column as:

```
val step2= step1
  .withColumn("distance",  distanceUDF(col("time_series1"),col("time_series2")))
  .select("websites","countryId1","countryId2","time_series1","time_series2","distance")
```

and the UDF :

```
 val distanceUDF  = udf( (ts1:Seq[(Float,_)], ts2:Seq[(Float,_)])=>
                            compute_distance( ts1.map(_._1) , ts2.map(_._1)))
```

but I have the problem on the mapping, I dont  know how to map the array (struct (float,date).to the scala.

Is `Seq[(Float,Date)]` equivalent to array( struct (float,date)) ? 
I have the following exeption:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: .GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2
```

My problem is different thant the one exposed here [Spark Sql UDF with complex input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413040/spark-sql-udf-with-complex-input-parameter) . I have an ordered time series withe date (i have an array and not only a struct type )

Answer (score 0):

The link you added has the answer to your question

> struct types are converted to o.a.s.sql.Row

So your function should take two Seq[Row] arguments.
Then you can use the [Row api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row) to get the floats.

In cases like this you may want to use [Datasets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets). For more about nested types you can watch [The Joy of Nested Types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v184Jb1wCYU)