# How to make generic UDF for Array of arbitrary types

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say  I want to make an spark UDF to reverse the ordering of an array of structs. The concrete type of the struct should not matter, so I tried:

```
val reverseUDF = udf((s:Seq[_]) => s.reverse)
```

But this gives

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
```

I also tried to use a generic method and force type generic type parameter to be a subtype of `Product`:

```
def reverse[T <: Product](s:Seq[T]) = {
  s.reverse
}

val reverseUDF = udf(reverse _)
```

This gives:

```
scala.MatchError: Nothing (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$6)
```

So is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. Spark has to know return output type and it is not possible to determine it using SQL expressions. You'll have to define specific `udf` for each type you want to use for example:

```
udf(reverse[(String, Int)] _)
udf(reverse[(String, Long, String)] _)
```

and so on. However none of these is useful in practice, because you'll never see `Product` type in your udf. A struct type is always encoded as `Row` - [Spark Sql UDF with complex input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38413040/9613318).

If you use Spark 2.3 you could express arbitrary `reverse` as:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType

def reverse(schema: DataType) = udf(
  (xs: Seq[Row]) => xs.map(x => Row.fromSeq(x.toSeq.reverse)),
  schema
)
```

but you'll have to provide schema for each instance: