# Spark: convert DataFrame column into vector

Tags: apache-spark, vector, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame `df` with a column `column` and I would like to convert `column` into a vector (e.g. a `DenseVector`) so that I can use it in vector and matrix products.

**Beware:** I don't need a column of vectors; I need a vector object.

How to do this?

I found out the `vectorAssembler` function ([link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler)) but this doesn't help me, as it converts some DataFrame columns into a vector columns, which is still a DataFrame column; my desired output should instead be a vector.

---

**About the goal of this question:** why am I trying to convert a DF column into a vector? Assume I have a DF with a numerical column and I need to compute a product between a matrix and this column. How can I achieve this? (The same could hold for a DF numerical row.) Any alternative approach is welcome.

Comment: please provide some sample data, along with the desired output

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138482/pyspark-how-do-i-convert-an-array-i-e-list-column-to-vector

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. If I understand well, this other post is trying to convert the type of a DF column; I rather want to extract a column from a DF and convert it into a vector, being it no longer a column of any DF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How:

```
DenseVector(df.select("column_name").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect())
```

**but it doesn't make sense** in any practical scenario.

Spark `Vectors` **are not distributed**, therefore are applicable only if data fits in memory of one (driver) node. If this is the case you wouldn't use Spark `DataFrame` for processing.

Comment: Well, so assume I have a DF with a numerical column and I need to compute a product between a matrix and this column. How can I achieve this? (The same could hold for a DF numerical row.)