# How to convert a dataframe of array of doubles to Vectors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe with array of doubles that need to be converted to Vectors in order to pass it to an ML algorithm. Can anyone help me with this?

```
fList: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: array<double>]
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2.5046410000000003, 2.1487149999999997, 1.0884870000000002, 3.5877090000000003]|
|[0.9558040000000001, 0.9843780000000002, 0.545025, 0.9979860000000002]          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected Output: 
Should look something like this.

```
fList: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: vector]
```

Comment: Take a look at this other question, maybe it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138482/pyspark-how-do-i-convert-an-array-i-e-list-column-to-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to write a `udf` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
def convertArrayToVector = udf((features: mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) => Vectors.dense(features.toArray))
```

and call that function in `withColumn` api

```
scala> df.withColumn("features", convertArrayToVector($"features"))
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: vector]
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: getting the error  <console>:62: error: not found: value mutable
       def convertArrayToVector = udf((features: mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) => Vectors.dense(features))

Comment: you have to import scala.collection._

Comment: Ramesh...I added the import statement which resolved that issue but facing a new one. Any idea on what this error is about ................import scala.collection._
<console>:55: error: overloaded method value dense with alternatives:
  (values: Array[Double])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector <and>
  (firstValue: Double,otherValues: Double*)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
 cannot be applied to (scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double])
       def convertArrayToVector = udf((features: mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) => Vectors.dense(features))

Comment: You have to convert the WrappedArray to Array . See in my answer that I did `Vectors.dense(features.toArray)` .toArray  is necessary