# Spark : Euclidean distance element-wise between two columns of vectors

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two DataFrames `df1` and `df2` which have the following structures :

```
print(df1)
+-------+------------+-------------+---------+
|     id|      vector|  start_time | end_time|
+-------+------------+-------------+---------+
|      1| [0,0,0,0,0]|          000|      200|
|      2| [1,1,1,1,1]|          200|      500|
|      3| [0,1,0,1,0]|          100|      500|
+-------+------------+-------------+---------+

print(df2)
+-------+------------+-------+
|     id|      vector|   time|
+-------+------------+-------+
|      A| [0,1,1,1,0]|    050|
|      B| [1,0,0,1,1]|    150|
|      C| [1,1,1,1,1]|    250|
|      D| [1,0,1,0,1]|    350|
|      E| [1,1,1,1,1]|    450|
|      F| [1,0,5,0,0]|    550|
+-------+------------+-------+
```

What I want is : For each data of `df1`, get all data from `df2` for which the `time` is between `start_time` and `end_time` and for all these data compute the euclidean distance between the two vectors.

I started with the following code, but I am stuck on the way to compute the distance :

```
val joined_DF = kafka_DF.crossJoin(
        hdfs_DF.withColumnRenamed("id","id2").withColumnRenamed("vector","vector2")
    )
      .filter(col("time")>= col("start_time") &&
        col("time")<= col("end_time"))
        .withColumn("distance", ???) // Euclidean distance element-wise between columns vector and column vector2
```

Here is the expected output on the example data:

```
+-------+------------+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------+----------+
|     id|      vector|  start_time | end_time|    id2|     vector2|  time| distance |
+-------+------------+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------+----------+
|      1| [0,0,0,0,0]|          000|      200|      A| [0,1,1,1,0]|   050|   1.73205|
|      1| [0,0,0,0,0]|          000|      200|      B| [1,0,0,1,1]|   150|   1.73205|
|      2| [1,1,1,1,1]|          200|      500|      C| [1,1,1,1,1]|   250|         0|
|      2| [1,1,1,1,1]|          200|      500|      D| [1,0,1,0,1]|   350|   1.41421|
|      2| [1,1,1,1,1]|          200|      500|      E| [1,1,1,1,1]|   450|         0|
|      3| [0,1,0,1,0]|          100|      500|      B| [1,0,0,1,1]|   150|   1.73205|
|      3| [0,1,0,1,0]|          100|      500|      C| [1,1,1,1,1]|   250|   1.73205|
|      3| [0,1,0,1,0]|          100|      500|      D| [1,0,1,0,1]|   350|   2.23606|
|      3| [0,1,0,1,0]|          100|      500|      E| [1,1,1,1,1]|   450|   1.73205|
+-------+------------+-------------+---------+-------+------------+------+----------+
```

Notes :

- `df1` will always have a little number of data, so the crossJoin will not risk to blow up my memory.
- My dataframes have been created using the Structured Streaming API.
- I am using Spark 2.3.2

Comment: what's the datatype of `vector`?

Comment: It's an array of Double

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `udf` should work in this case.

```
import math._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

//input two vectors of length n, but must be equal length
//output euclidean distance between the vectors
val euclideanDistance = udf { (v1: Vector, v2: Vector) =>
    sqrt(Vectors.sqdist(v1, v2))
}
```

Utilize your new `udf` like this:

```
joined_DF.withColumn("distance", euclideanDistance($"vector", $"vector2"))
```

Comment: i think you have a typo there, " = {"  and you should have this "=>"

Comment: Indeed, I did. I started with two functions and merged them on SO without testing the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: The input column type is Array[Double], how do you cast to Vector type ?

Comment: You could use the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543887/2639647, or you could modify the provided function slightly to accept `Array[Double]`, and use `Vectors.dense(v1)` and `Vectors.dense(v2)` as the parameters to `Vectors.sqdist()`. I'm not sure if/how the OP dealt with that.

Comment: How to implement this in PySpark?