# IllegalArgumentException: Column must be of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> but was actually double.'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataframe with multiple categorical columns. I'm trying to find the the chisquared statistics using the in-built function between two columns:

```
from pyspark.ml.stat import ChiSquareTest

r = ChiSquareTest.test(df, 'feature1', 'feature2')
```

However, it gives me the error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Column feature1 must be of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> but was actually double.'
```

The datatype for `feature1` is:

```
feature1: double (nullable = true)
```

Could you please help me with this regard?

Comment: I was getting the same error when calculating the vector norm. I used `array_to_vector` from `pyspark.ml.functions` to convert the array column to a vector type. Only available in **pyspark>=3.1.0**. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48333361/2650427.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`spark-ml` is not the typical statistics library. It is very ML oriented. Therefore it assumes that you will want to run a test between a label and a feature or a group of features.

Therefore, similarly to when you train a model, you need to assemble the features you want to test against the label.

In your case, you can just assemble `feature1` as follows:

```py
from pyspark.ml.stat import ChiSquareTest
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

data = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 1), (4, 3)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['feature1', 'feature2'])
assembler = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(['feature1']).setOutputCol('features')

ChiSquareTest.test(assembler.transform(df), 'features', 'feature2').show(false)
```

Just in case, the code in scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.ChiSquareTest
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val df = Seq((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (6, 5, 4))
    .toDF("features", "feature2", "feature3")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("feature1"))
    .setOutputCol("features")

ChiSquareTest.test(assembler.transform(df), "features", "feature2").show(false)
```

Answer (score 9):

To expand on Oli's answer, Spark ML expects features to be stored in instances of `pyspark.ml.linalg.Vector`. There are two kinds of vectors:

- dense vectors - those are simply arrays that hold all elements of the vector, including all zeros, and are represented by a Spark array type `array<T>`
- sparse vectors - those are more complex data structures that only store non-zero elements of a vector, allowing compact storage of huge vectors with just a small number of non-zeros. Sparse vectors have three components:

  - an integer `size` that indicates the full dimension of the vector
  - an `indices` array that holds the positions of the non-zero elements
  - a `values` array that holds the values of the non-zero elements

Both vector types are actually represented using the structure for sparse vectors, whereas for dense vectors the `indices` array goes unused and `values` stores all of the values. The first structure element, `type`, is used to distinguish between the two kinds.

So, if you see an error that something expects `struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>`, that means you are supposed to pass an instances of `pyspark.ml.linagl.Vector` and not mere numbers.

In order to produce `Vector`s, you can either use `pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler` to assemble one or more independent feature columns into a single vector column or manually construct them using the factory methods `Vectors.dense()` (for dense vectors) and `Vectors.sparse()` (for sparse vectors) of the factory object `pyspark.ml.linalg.Vectors`. Using `VectorAssembler` is probably easier and also faster since it's implemented in Scala. For use of explicit vector creation, consult the [example for `ChiSquareTest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.stat.ChiSquareTest) in the PySpark documentation.