Scala DataSet with case class inheritance
I'd like to be able to store different related types in a Spark DataFrame but work with strongly typed case classes via a DataSet. E.g. say I have a Base trait and two case classes A and B that extend the trait:
trait Base {
  def name: String
}

case class A(name: String, number: Int) extends Base

case class B(name: String, text: String) extends Base


I'd like to create a val lb = List[Base](A("Alice", 20), B("Bob", "Foo")) and then create a DataFrame via lb.toDS(). Not surprisingly, this doesn't work as there is no encoder for the trait for it's different extended classes.
I could manually create a case class representing a structure that can hold information for both A and B:
case class Struct(typ: String, name: String, number: Option[Int] = None, text: Option[String] = None)

And I could add some functions to create a Struct from an instance of a Base trait and vice vera:
trait Base {
  def name: String

  def asStruct: Struct = {
    this match {
      case A(name, number) => Struct("A", name, number = Some(number))
      case B(name, text) => Struct("B", name, text = Some(text))
    }
  }
}

case class Struct(typ: String, name: String, number: Option[Int] = None, text: Option[String] = None) {
  def asBase: Base = {
    this match {
      case Struct("A", name, Some(number), None) => A(name, number)
      case Struct("B", name, None, Some(text)) => B(name, text)
      case _ => throw new Exception(f"Invalid Base structure {s}")
    }
  }
}

Then I can create my DataFrame as follows:
    val a = A("Alice", 32)
    val b = B("Bob", "foo")

    val ls = List[Struct](a.asStruct, b.asStruct)

    val sparkSession = spark
    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val df = ls.toDS()

    df.show()

+---+-----+------+----+
|typ| name|number|text|
+---+-----+------+----+
|  A|Alice|    32|NULL|
|  B|  Bob|  NULL| foo|
+---+-----+------+----+

I can work with this approach but I wondered if it is possible to write an encoder that automatically treats a Base class as a Struct using the asStruct method written above?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030073/encode-an-adt-sealed-trait-hierarchy-into-spark-dataset-column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502726/spark-dataset-how-to-add-subclass-objects-to-dataset-of-parent-class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440461/how-to-define-schema-for-custom-type-in-spark-sql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926555/spark-dataframe-to-sealed-trait-type

Thank you, I don't know why I couldn't find those articles when I searched.

frameless injections:
// the injector
implicit val baseHolder: Injection[Base, Struct] = new Injection[Base, Struct] with Serializable {
  def invert(a: Struct): Base =
    a match {
      case Struct("A", name, Some(number), None) => A(name, number)
      case Struct("B", name, None, Some(text)) => B(name, text)
      case _ => throw new Exception(f"Invalid Base structure {s}")
    }

  def apply(b: Base): Struct =
    b match {
      case A(name, number) => Struct("A", name, number = Some(number))
      case B(name, text) => Struct("B", name, text = Some(text))
    }
}
import frameless._
implicit val enc = TypedExpressionEncoder[Base]

import sparkSession.implicits._
val lb: Dataset[Base] = Seq[Base](A("Alice", 20), B("Bob", "Foo")).toDS
lb.show

yields:
+---+-----+------+----+
|typ| name|number|text|
+---+-----+------+----+
|  A|Alice|    20|null|
|  B|  Bob|  null| Foo|
+---+-----+------+----+

but are they really A's and B's?
lb.collect().foreach{ b =>
  println(b.getClass.getName)
}

will show A and B.
The parameter order on injections is important, the left one is the one we create the injection for and the 2nd parameter is the type we store it as in the dataframe.

That's very neat. Exactly what I was looking for.

Chris, one more question. I tested having a dataset formed from a case class that contains Base fields. If I call a UDF that takes a Base parameter then the decoding doesn't work...instead the UDF is passed the Struct type. Is this a limitation or is there some other implicit that I can declare to get the Struct to be converted into A or B?

This was my case class 'case class C(x: Base, y: Base)' and my test:     val a = A("Alice", 32)
val b = B("Bob", "foo")
val lb = Seq(C(a, b))
val ds: Dataset[C] = lb.toDS

def processBase(b: Base): String = {
  b match {
    case A(name, number) => f"$name has number $number"
    case B(name, text) => f"$name has text $text"
    case _ => "Don't know"
  }
}
val processBaseUdf = udf(processBase(_))

var df = ds.withColumn("x", processBaseUdf(ds("x")))
df = df.withColumn("y", processBaseUdf(ds("y")))


you should probably ask this as a different question and show the code, I assume the type derivation for C is wrong and you should use: implicit val cenc = TypedExpressionEncoder[C]

also you'd need to state if you are testing locally or in a shaded jar (relocating scala with maven shade does not work)

Ok, I'll set up the cenc as see if that works. If not, I'll do another question and show all the code. Thanks for the help.

I've asked the question about decoding and UDFs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78349325/spark-udf-doesnt-get-decoded-dataset-class-using-org-typelevel-frameless-encode
