# DataType (UDT) v.s. Encoder in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, user-defined-types, apache-spark-encoders

In Spark SQL, there're [limited `DataType`s](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types) for `Schema`, and there're [limited `Encoder`s](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala) for converting JVM objects to and from the internal Spark SQL representation.

- In practice, we may have errors like this regarding `DataType`, which usually happens in a `DataFrame` with custom types, **BUT NOT** in a `Dataset[T]` with custom types. Discussion of `DataType` (or `UDT`) points to [How to define schema for custom type in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440461/how-to-define-schema-for-custom-type-in-spark-sql)

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type xxx is not supported

- In practice, we may have errors like this regarding `Encoder`, which usually happens in a `Dataset[T]` with custom types, **BUT NOT** in a `DataFrame` with custom types. Discussion of `Encoder` points to [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset)

> Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases

In my understanding, both touches the internal Spark SQL optimizer (which is why only a limited number of `DataType`s and `Encoder`s are provided); and both `DataFrame` and `Dataset` are just `Dataset[A]`, then..

**Question** (or more.. confusion)

- Why first error only appears in `DataFrame` but not in `Dataset[T]`? Same question for the second error...
- Can creating `UDT` solve the 2nd error? Can creating encoders solve the 1st error?
- How should I understand the relation between each, and how do they interact with `Dataset` or Spark SQL engine?

The initiative of this post is to **explore** more in the two concepts and to attract **open discussion**, so please bear a bit if the questions are not too specific.. and any sharing of understanding is appreciated. Thanks.